# Google BarChart decimal values Not appears

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am creating google barchart, that takes data from database.The problem is that data contains values below "1" like 0.6,0.7 etc
It wont appear on graph. Graph only shows values starting from 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>); 
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
type: 'string',
role: 'annotation',
sourceColumn: 1,
calc: 'stringify'
}]);
    var options = {
        width: 395,
        height: 200,
    title: 'Values',
       'chartArea': {right: 37,width:'40%'},
        titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 14
  },
legend: {position: 'none'},
colors:['#4A9218'],
           }; 
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('ch7')); 
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
</script>
<div id="ch7" style="width:33%; height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: Update your question with an example of the data output by `<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>` that demonstrates the problem.  I made a fiddle based on this code, and it seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/YhG4y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are all positive you can use logarithmic scale setting option `hAxis.logScale` to `true`. Othervise you can set also minimum value to be shown. Options are set like:

```
        hAxis: {
            logScale: true
        }
```

or like

```
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0
        }
```

Comment: I changed how it should be set. Before it was written as in reference page, see [Bar chart conf. options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options)

Comment: Thanks a lot! the real problem was in mysql->json, where I had to change int to double. my script was getting values in int format, therefore not showing decimal values.